# gwt - How to remove TextBox internal whitespace/padding?

Tags: gwt, textbox, padding, font-size

I have a gwt TextBox whose height is determined by a variable:

```java
aTextBox = new TextBox();
parentLayoutPanel.add(aTextBox);
parentLayoutPanel.setWidgetTopHeight(aTextBox, 0.0, Unit.PX, text_box_height, Unit.PX);
```

This variable `text_box_height` is unknown until the page loads. Now I want to make sure the font inside the box matches the size of the box. Currently, I'm attempting to the following:

```java
aTextBox.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("fontSize", Integer.toString(text_box_height) + "px");
```

Unfortunately, this results in white space above the text which cuts off the bottom of the text:

[image: textBoxFont]

How can I remove this white space/padding? Or is there a different way to size and position the text in the box? Thank you much!

**EDIT: Additional information:**
Due to the comments, I've added the following image. The line is the cursor marker.
[image]

Comment: Use a different letter - like F - and you will see a very different white space.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I still get the same white space with an 'F'.

Comment: Have you tried  vertical-align: middle; ??

Comment: @TheSureshAtta, attempting that now. It didn't seem to work, but when I look at the resulting source code I don't seem to see the style add the input element. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @TheSureshAtta, nevermind. The style is correctly added, but I am still getting the same thing.

Comment: @TheSureshAtta, I've added another image showing the resulting element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I've found that the space taken up by the line of text is 1.5x that of the font-size. I don't see a way to change that whitespace. I ended up actually just setting the box being 1.5x as much as the font-size.

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding on TextBox just like you can set it on any element. You can use `.getElement().getStyle()`, or you can apply a CSS style.

Comment: Using `aTextBox.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("padding", "0px");` doesn't change it. Also, I've tried adding a CSS style which takes the padding, margin, and border down to zero, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: I've added another image which shows the input having the correct style, yet still not displaying correctly. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You have to use "0px !important" to override default GWT style.